# MIME type issue with css, js and images

Tags: javascript, css, server, mime

I have just deployed my Django website on alwaysdata. But I do have a problem : when I ask for a page, html files are sent and displayed but not css, javascript and image files. And I have the following messages in the console :

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

Would you know where is the problem coming from ?

(By the way, I have added this in my .htaccess :

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType application/javascript .js
etc
```

)